# How to monitor another .exe and perform action if it closes

Tags: c#, winforms

Currently have a program that opens another program. I need to perform an action should that program close. I am pretty new to C# so could use some help getting me pointed in the correct direction.

EDIT: So I am able to get the current form to open the external program. This form then needs to close and another form needs to have a function to perform an action should the loader.exe close. This is what I have in the first form. How do I code the other form to know if this program has ended.

```
public static class Program
{
    public static bool OpenManager { get; set; }
    public static int DeskNumber { get; set; }

    /// The main entry point for the application.

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] arguments)
    {
        /// Do not move this!
        OpenManager = false;
        MYvariable = 0;
        /// ----------------

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Loader());

        if (OpenManager)
        {
            if (MYvariable == 1)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process startProgram = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("loader.exe", "-r 52");
                startProgram.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                Application.Run(new Manager());
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use the [`Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process) class to start the other program, you can subscribe to the [`Exited`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exited) event of the `Process` instance:

```
Process myProcess = Process.Start("myprogram.exe", "arguments");
myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
myProcess.Exited += (sender, e) => 
    {
       // Do what you want to do when the process exited.
    }
```

Or, to do it more explicit, declare an explicit event handler that is called when the process finishes:

```
public void OnProcessExited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Do what you want to do when the process exited.
}

public void StartProcess()
{
    Process myProcess = Process.Start("myprogram.exe", "arguments");
    myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    myProcess.Exited += OnProcessExited;
}
```

Comment: Will this allow the initial process to still function and perform other actions? sorry if this is a really newb question.

Comment: @DavidBentley Yes of course. You only _register_ to the event. So if the created process terminates `OnProcessExited` is called. (Watch out, I'm not really sure if this is called on the same thread that started the process.) But execution is _not_ blocked while that process is running.

Comment: Ok, so will this also work if I am opening the external program in one form and then that form closes and another form opens? The new form is what is needed to monitor the running process.

Comment: @DavidBentley Yes as long as the event handler method (`OnProcessExited` in my example) is still valid. You did not show any code, so I can't show an example for your specific needs, and I'm afk now. If you closed your first form, the event handler should not try to access this form or any control on it, as it will already be disposed when the handler is executed.

Comment: Thanks a billion. If it fails I will throw some code in so you can see what I am doing.

Comment: Ok, I have added code since I have having trouble getting the second form that opens to work.

Comment: So I moved my code to the main Program.cs that has the entry point for all my forms to load since it seemed easier to do that here. Now I am to the point where I want the "manager" form that opens to keep track of the loader.exe program.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the Process class within c# to open and keep a track on the opened program you can handle its exited event like so:

```
App.Exited += AppOnExited;

private static void AppOnExited(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    // Do your action here
}
```

App being the name of your process object.

dont forget you may need to remove the handler when your done like so:

```
App.Exited -= AppOnExited;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the application returns an `int` code you can use:

```
Process P = Process.Start("App.exe");
P.WaitForExit();
int code = P.ExitCode;
```

An application that has `return`:

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    return (int);
}
```

Will set `P.ExitCode` to the return value when it closes.